# Alarm manager only being called once, also service not being called within BroadcastReceiver

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have created a local notification service, which works on load, then i created a alarm receiver to call this service every hour, however the service is not called and the alarm only runs once. I have added the reference to the Manifest. 
I'm not sure how to fix this

AlarmReceiver

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
public class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(context, "Received intent!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        Intent not = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(Services.NotifcationService));
        Application.Context.StartService(not);


    }
}
```

Service

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;

namespace example.Services
{
    [Service(Label = "NotifcationService")]
    [IntentFilter(new String[] { "com.example.NotifcationService" })]
    public class NotifcationService : Service
    {
        IBinder binder;

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Android.Content.Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            const int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

            Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.logoArrow)
                .SetContentTitle("Sample Notication")
                .SetContentText("Hello World! This is my first notification");

            var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
            notificationManager.Notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.Build());

            return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
        }

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            binder = new NotifcationServiceBinder(this);
            return binder;
        }
    }

    public class NotifcationServiceBinder : Binder
    {
        readonly NotifcationService service;

        public NotifcationServiceBinder(NotifcationService service)
        {
            this.service = service;
        }

        public NotifcationService GetNotifcationService()
        {
            return service;
        }
    }
}
```

Main Activity

```
        this.context = this;
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
        var pending = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        var alarmManager = GetSystemService(AlarmService).JavaCast<AlarmManager>();
        alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtime, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + 5 * 1000, pending);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run alarm time to time, you should use `alarmManager.SetRepeating` as per documentation:

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.AlarmManager.SetRepeating/p/Android.App.AlarmType/System.Int64/System.Int64/Android.App.PendingIntent/